# Circuit Simulator

Tags: go, simulation

I'm trying to learn Golang from Java, and to do this, I wrote a basic circuit simulator with only two circuits. Is there anything I can do better to make it more idiomatic?

**Simulator.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

const ITERATIONS = 10

func main() {
    a := Wire{false, false}
    b := Wire{false, false}
    c := Wire{false, false}
    d := Wire{false, false}

    ga := NotGate{&a, &b}
    gb := XorGate{&b, &c, &d}

    wires := []*Wire{&a, &b, &c, &d}
    gates := []Gate{ga, gb}

    for i := 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++ {
        for _, w := range wires {
            fmt.Print("%d: {%t, %t}\n", i, w.BeginningValue, w.EndValue)
            w.Execute()
        }
        for _, g := range gates {
            g.Execute()
        }

    }
}

type Wire struct {
    BeginningValue bool
    EndValue       bool
}

func (wire *Wire) Execute() {
    wire.EndValue = wire.BeginningValue
}

type Gate interface {
    Execute()
}
```

**XorGate.go**

```
package main

import ()

type XorGate struct {
    A      *Wire
    B      *Wire
    Output *Wire
}

func (gate XorGate) Execute() {
    gate.Output.BeginningValue = gate.A.EndValue != gate.B.EndValue
}
```

**NotGate.go**

```
package main

import ()

type NotGate struct {
    A      *Wire
    Output *Wire
}

func (gate NotGate) Execute() {
    gate.Output.BeginningValue = !gate.A.EndValue
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is neat, and structured just like I would expect to see Java ;-) - separate files for each "class".

In your case, though, the separation in to files is probably over the top, and if you are talking idiomatic go, I would not expect to see separate files for the NotGate and the XorGate.

There is a small bug in your code, you use: `fmt.Print("%d: {%t, %t}\n", i, w.BeginningValue, w.EndValue)` where that should be a `Printf` and not a `Print`.

You have declared the `Gate` interface, and I understand why you have it, but there's a subtle thing about interfaces in go, they are not the same as Java. Go uses duck-typing, and, because you have an `Execute` method on the ***pointer*** to `Wire`, it is also actually a `Gate` too. You may not be expecting that.

You have an inconsistency in your pointers too. You keep your `wires` as pointers to your `Wire` instances, but you keep your `gates` as the actual Gate values.

I would expect that your `Execute` methods on the `Notgate` and `XorGate` should be on the pointer to them, not on the actual gate. Thus, your methods are currently:

> ```
> func (gate XorGate) Execute() {
>     gate.Output.BeginningValue = gate.A.EndValue != gate.B.EndValue
> }
>
> func (gate NotGate) Execute() {
>     gate.Output.BeginningValue = !gate.A.EndValue
> }
> ```

but should be:

```
func (gate *XorGate) Execute() {
    gate.Output.BeginningValue = gate.A.EndValue != gate.B.EndValue
}

func (gate *NotGate) Execute() {
    gate.Output.BeginningValue = !gate.A.EndValue
}
```

This makes the `*XorGate` and the `*NotGate` implement the `Gate` interface. Before it was the `XorGate` and `NotGate` that implemented it. I know, subtle difference, but, what this means is that your line of code:

> ```
> gates := []Gate{ga, gb}
> ```

can be:

```
gates := []Gate{&ga, &gb}
```

The value of the above changes is that now you have consistency in the use of gates and wires.

Talking wires, your initialization of your various wires would be considered redundant in go - in go, it is idiomatic to ignore the specification of zero-values. The zero-value of a boolean is `false`, so specifying it is wrong. Your code:

> ```
> a := Wire{false, false}
> b := Wire{false, false}
> c := Wire{false, false}
> d := Wire{false, false}
> ```

Should just be:

```
a := Wire{}
b := Wire{}
c := Wire{}
d := Wire{}
```

Note, in the above, that `a`, `b`, etc. all are actual wires. It would also be idiomatic to resort to having everything in pointer-space, and use the `new` keyword.... `new(...)` returns a pointer to the value.

The result would be:

```
a := new(Wire)
b := new(Wire)
c := new(Wire)
d := new(Wire)

ga := &NotGate{a, b}
gb := &XorGate{b, c, d}

wires := []*Wire{a, b, c, d}
gates := []Gate{ga, gb}
```

Note, taking the pointer at the initialization of the `NotGate` and `XorGate` brings those in to pointer-space as well.

You are missing a bunch of documentation on the exported methods, types and constants ;-)

All told, I would expect your program to look like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

const ITERATIONS = 10

type Wire struct {
    BeginningValue bool
    EndValue       bool
}

func (wire *Wire) Execute() {
    wire.EndValue = wire.BeginningValue
}

type Gate interface {
    Execute()
}

type XorGate struct {
    A      *Wire
    B      *Wire
    Output *Wire
}

func (gate *XorGate) Execute() {
    gate.Output.BeginningValue = gate.A.EndValue != gate.B.EndValue
}

type NotGate struct {
    A      *Wire
    Output *Wire
}

func (gate *NotGate) Execute() {
    gate.Output.BeginningValue = !gate.A.EndValue
}

func main() {
    a := new(Wire)
    b := new(Wire)
    c := new(Wire)
    d := new(Wire)

    ga := &NotGate{a, b}
    gb := &XorGate{b, c, d}

    wires := []*Wire{a, b, c, d}
    gates := []Gate{ga, gb}

    for i := 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++ {
        for _, w := range wires {
            fmt.Printf("%d: {%t, %t}\n", i, w.BeginningValue, w.EndValue)
            w.Execute()
        }
        for _, g := range gates {
            g.Execute()
        }

    }
}
```

See it in the playground here: https://play.golang.org/p/VdN4driYRn

Finally, I take some exception to the actual circuit nature of your code ;-) A Wire does not have different beginning and ending values - a wire is a single-state thing.... I am not sure why your values change on each iteration, I think your simulation is based on a broken understanding of logic. I would instead model the circuit as having a "Value()" and then find a way to chase back (recursively) what that Value would be when called.

Comment: Thank you for the great review! Also, the only reason I didn't do what you were proposing at the end is because of the case of circular connections. I wasn't really sure what the real world behavior was, but I'm sure it's not a stackoverflow exception.

Comment: After switching to `*Gate`, doesn't the declaration change to `gates := []*Gate{...}` just as with `wires`?

Comment: @DavidHarkness `Gate` will be an interface after the change, so the pointer is sort of implied.

Comment: I'm still just learning, but are you saying that because `Gate` is an interface you can assign two `*XorGate` (which conform to the interface) to a `[]Gate` without declaring it `[]*Gate`? Is there even a concept of a pointer to an interface, or does that not even make sense? Separating the idea of interfaces from Java is probably going to take some practice. :)

Comment: @DavidHarkness : See https://play.golang.org/p/T7sLjGFBgc and ping me in the 2nd if you want to chat ;-)

Comment: Too late to edit, but see this too: http://research.swtch.com/interfaces

Comment: Wow, you can really bend the rules! I didn't know that the automatic dereferencing of `.` also applies when checking if a type implements an interface: https://play.golang.org/p/TjVeiIzylB